# Outputting Certain lines in a txt file based off User Input

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a txt file which contains a list of all the Basketball Games played in the 2017-2018 Season, the date the game was held, and the final score. These three pieces of data are placed in one line and each game contains these three pieces of data. However, I only want to output the lines which contains the two teams that are inputted by a user. For example, if the Golden State Warriors and the Los Angeles Lakers played 4 times, I want to only output those 4 lines in that entire list. I'm not sure how to have the txt file output the lines which match the two teams which the user inputs.

I know that there has to be a loop which reads through the txt file and matches all the lines which contain both the nba teams and then outputs those lines.

My txt file is called games.txt

So a sample of games.txt is

```
Tue Oct 17 2017,8:01p,Boston Celtics,99,Cleveland Cavaliers,102,
Tue Oct 17 2017,10:30p,Houston Rockets,122,Golden State Warriors,121,
Wed Oct 18 2017,7:30p,Milwaukee Bucks,108,Boston Celtics,100,
```

Regarding desired output, I just want to print out the entire line which matches the 2 teams . For example, if the user typed Milwaukee Bucks and Boston Celtics, output the entire third line.

Comment: Nice question, but can you show the data?, and the desired output?, your current attempt?

Comment: Share a sample of `games.txt` and also add expected output.

Comment: Updated the question to contain helpful information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def f(t1,t2):
    with open('games.txt','r') as f:
       return '\n'.join([i for i in f if t1 in i and t2 in i])
```

Just open and output.

To call (example two teams of Milwaukee Bucks and Boston Celtics):

```
print(f('Milwaukee Bucks','Boston Celtics'))
```

Output:

```
Wed Oct 18 2017,7:30p,Milwaukee Bucks,108,Boston Celtics,100,
```

Comment: What if the order is reversed? Might not some games list the Celtics first and then the Bucks?

Comment: The order being reversed doesn't matter. The output stays the same regardless